# Axios useState in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-state

I am brand new to JS and react, so I might be way off with my attempts so far, and also, my code is full of console.log for debugging, but the problem I am having is:

I have a functional component with a changeHandler and submitHandler function within.
changeHandler is triggered by a 'file' input while submitHandler is called on form submission.
The submitHandler makes 2calls to 2 separate end-points via axios:
1st - to create a new record in a DB
2nd - adds a file to that same record.

I want to use the res.roundId from the first call as a dynamic variable in the 2nd axios.post request.

I update the state of the 'details' (roundId) on line 29 using:
setDetails(prevDetails=>({
...prevDetails,
roundId:res.data.roundId
}))

However, the roundId is not updated to the res.data.roundId and therefore I cannot destructure this for the 2nd axios call.

Any suggestions on how I might achieve this?
Full code below:

```
const FileUpload = () => {

const [file, setFile]= useState(null)
const[details, setDetails] = useState({consent:false, 
                            idConfirmed:false, 
                            label:"", 
                            roundId:""})

const changeHandler=(e)=>{
    
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setDetails(prevDetails=>({
        ...prevDetails,
        consent:true,
        idConfirmed:true,
        label:"test_Label"
    }));
};

const handleSubmission=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
            axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_URL_NEW_ROUND, details)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log("Full Details: ", res)
                console.log("roundId: ", res.data.roundId)
                setDetails(prevDetails=>({
                    ...prevDetails,
                    roundId:res.data.roundId
                }))
                console.log("line 31 Details: ", details)
            })
        
            console.log("roundId line 34: ", details.roundId )

          //console.log("Details", details)
    
         const data = new FormData();

         data.append("file", file)

        axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_URL_All_ROUNDS/details.roundId/file/upload", data)
        .then(res=>{
            console.log("Data: ",res.data)
            console.log("success")
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
            console.log("Error", e)
        })
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a React behaviour. `setDetails` hook updates your `details` not immediately. It means you cannot use `details` right after calling `setDetails`. To use the response from the first axios call in the second axios call it makes sense to `res.data.roundId` value directly.

Also in your case you should put the second axios call inside the first call callback, because it's async operations. Otherwise, these 2 calls start execute in parallel, but you need to execute it sequently to make it possible to rely the second call on the first call.

```
const handleSubmission=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
            axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_URL_NEW_ROUND, details)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log("Full Details: ", res)
                console.log("roundId: ", res.data.roundId)
                setDetails(prevDetails=>({
                    ...prevDetails,
                    roundId:res.data.roundId
                }))
                console.log("line 31 Details: ", details)
         const data = new FormData();

         data.append("file", file)

axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL_All_ROUNDS}/${res.data.roundId}/file/upload`, data)
        .then(res=>{
            console.log("Data: ",res.data)
            console.log("success")
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
            console.log("Error", e)
        })
            })
        
            console.log("roundId line 34: ", details.roundId )

          //console.log("Details", details)
    


    
    };
```